# Deployment using Gitlab and Turborepo plus NextJs

Tags: next.js, gitlab, turborepo

Do someone have success deploying nextjs standalone apps from turborepo using gitlab-ci?

I need some examples of deployment using gitlab, turborepo and nextjs.